# How to Update multiple column with Multiple condition

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to update multiple columns in a table with multiple condition.

For example, this is my Query

```
update Table1 
set weight= d.weight,
    stateweight=d.stateweight,
    overallweight=d.overallweight 
from
     (select * from table2)d 
      where table1.state=d.state and
          table1.month=d.month and 
          table1.year=d.year
```

If table matches all the three column (State,month,year), it should update only **weight column** and  if it matches(state ,year) it should update only the **stateweight column** and if it matches(year) it should update only the **overallweight column**

**NOTE:** I can't write an update query for each condition separately because its a huge `select`

Table1

```
Year Month State Weight StateWeight Overweight
2014  1     AA    0.00    0.00        0.00
2014  3     AA    0.00    0.00        0.00
2014  1     AB    0.00    0.00        0.00
2014  2     AB    0.00    0.00        0.00
2014  3     AC    0.00    0.00        0.00
2014  1     DD    0.00    0.00        0.00
```

Table2

```
Year Month State Weight StateWeight Overweight
2014  1     AA    2.20    5.00        2.22
2014  2     AA    1.70    5.00        2.22
2014  3     AA    8.30    5.00        2.22
2014  1     AB    5.80    2.11        2.22
2014  2     AB    7.40    2.11        2.22
2014  3     AB    9.10    2.11        2.22
2014  1     AC    3.42    5.14        2.22
2014  1     DD    8.88    9.00        2.22
```

My Result should be (My Updated Table1 should be )

```
Year Month State Weight StateWeight Overweight
2014  1     AA    2.20    5.00        2.22
2014  3     AA    8.30    5.00        2.22
2014  1     AB    5.80    2.11        2.22
2014  2     AB    7.40    2.11        2.22
2014  3     AC    0.00    0.00        2.22
2014  1     DD    0.00    9.00        2.22
```

but the query which u given were updated only Overweight Column not other 2 column(weight & StateWeight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by changing the criteria in your where clause, and adding case statements to the update.

Here is an example:

```
with
cte as  (   select      t1.Year,
                        t1.Month,
                        t1.State,
                        Weight      =   MAX(case
                                                when t1.State = t2.State and t1.Month = t2.Month
                                                then t2.Weight
                                                else t1.Weight
                                            end),
                        StateWeight =   MAX(case
                                            when t1.State = t2.State and t1.Month = t2.Month
                                            then t2.StateWeight
                                            else t1.StateWeight
                                        end),
                        Overweight  =   MAX(t2.Overweight)
            from        Table1  as  t1
            inner join  Table2  as  t2  on  t1.Year = t2.Year
            group by    t1.Year, t1.Month, t1.State)
update      t1
set         Weight  =   tv.Weight,
            StateWeight =   tv.StateWeight,
            Overweight = tv.Overweight
from        Table1  as  t1
inner join  cte     as  tv  on  t1.Year = tv.Year
                            and t1.Month = tv.Month
                            and t1.State = tv.State;
```

Comment: Sry for the delayed update it only updates the overallweight column ,not other 2 column were updated... pls help me...

Comment: Hi @SathishA, can you please update your question to include the definition of Table1 and Table2, and also provide some examples of the data that would be contained in each table?

Comment: Hi @SathishA, I have updated my answer based on the additional information you have provided.